# Bind datagridview to List<Dictionary<string, string>>

Tags: c#, dictionary, datagridview, bind

How can I bind a datagridview to a list of dictionary?
Example:

```
public static List<Dictionary<string, string>> listDict = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
Dictionary<string, string> dictPanier = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dictPanier["ean"] = txtStockEAN.Text;//1, 2, ...
dictPanier["titre"] = txtStockTitre.Text;// titre1, titre2, ...
dictPanier["prix"] = txtStockPrix.Text;//10, 20
dictPanier["quantite"] = txtStockQuantite.Text; // 100, 200
listDict.Add(dictPanier);
```

the dataGridView1 has 4 columns (ean, titre, prix, quantite), it must be seen like this:

```
ean    |     titre     |    prix    |     quantite     
__________________________________________________
1      |     titre1    |    10      |     100          
2      |     titre2    |    20      |     200          
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary itself is list (read collection). But Dictionary is not a correct collection for binding. It has other usage.

However you can do

```
public class Foo
{        
    public int Ean { get; set; }
    public string Titre { get; set; }
    public int Prix { get; set; }
    public int Quantite { get; set; }
}

List<Foo> lst = new List<Foo>();

Foo f = new  Foo();
f.Ean = Convert.ToInt32(txtStockEAN.Text);
f.Titre = txtStockTitre.Text;
f.Prix = Convert.ToInt32(txtStockPrix.Text);
f.Quantite = Convert.ToInt32(txtStockQuantite.Text);
lst.Add(f);
```

Comment: In my WinForm I added a button which function is: `private void btnPanierAjouter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){ //your code(without class foo)
dataGridView1.DataSource=lst;
}
`
When I clicked it in the first time, the result is added to the dataGridView1, but when I clicked it again there is no changes, why?

Comment: I added this code and its okey `    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();  bs.DataSource = lst;  dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;`
thinks